# Break down a pcap file into individual flows and modify them

Tags: networking, pcap

I have a pcap file and I want to:

1. separate every flow
2. separate responses and requests in each flow
3. modify ip and port in some packets
4. reply packets

Is there any utility in linux that helps me for do this?

Comment: Yes, there are a few. Look at `tcpick` for separating TCP flow for instance. `apt-cache search` on Debian based system is your friend.

Comment: What do you mean by _4. reply packets_?

Comment: My *guess* is that user3686476 means "*replay* packets", i.e. send the modified packets on the network.